# mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to receive - Connection refused in Centos 7 client

Tags: centos, centos7, nfs, nfsclient

I am trying to connect to a nfs server. where i seeing the below issue.

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon May 11 19:27:01 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=IP'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Unable to receive - Connection refused
```

nfs-utils is installed and running in the client. 
rpcbind is running in the client machine. 
Ports 111, 2049 and 892 are opened to the NFS server.
However i am not sure if i am missing anything to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the mount command and the relevant export on the server side.